# How to set the transform origin to a specific point on the element?

Tags: css, svg, css-transforms

In this example I want to rotate the hammer from its bottom so is there a way to know exactly the right coordinates of a specific point on the element or should I randomly try different points?

```css
svg {
  width: 50%;
}

.hammer-icon {
  transform-origin: 200px 50px;
  transition: transform .3s ease-out;
}

.hammer:hover .hammer-icon {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 -50 400 200">
  <g class="hammer">
    <circle class="hammer-bg" fill="#FFD466" cx="200" cy="50" r="90"></circle>
    <path class="hammer-icon" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M262,32.9l-6.7-6.9c-1.4-1.4-3.6-1.4-5-0.1l-2.8,2.8l-14.6-15c-7-7.2-20.3-18.5-30.1-16.4
      c-1.6,0.3-5.6,3.1-5.6,3.1l19,19.5l-26.3,25.6l-1.5-1.6c-1.4-1.4-3.6-1.4-5-0.1l-39.3,38.3c-1.4,1.4-1.4,3.6-0.1,5l14.4,14.8
      c1.4,1.4,3.6,1.4,5,0.1l39.3-38.3c1.4-1.4,1.4-3.6,0.1-5l-1.5-1.6l26.3-25.6l8.3,8.5l-2.8,2.8c-1.4,1.4-1.4,3.6-0.1,5l6.7,6.9
      c1.4,1.4,3.6,1.4,5,0.1l17.3-16.9C263.3,36.5,263.4,34.3,262,32.9z"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make the `transform-origin` point relative to the element, you need to use [`transform-box: fill-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box).

<del>Chrome doesn't support that property yet ([CSS transform-box - Chrome Platform Status](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6643927633362944#consensus)), but luckily (yet wrongfully) Chrome sets the `transform-origin` relative to the element if you use percentages instead of pixels (https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/).</del>

So, to make something that works on most *) modern browsers, use `transform-box: fill-box;` and `transform-origin: xx% yy%;`

```
.hammer-icon {
    transform-origin: 15% 80%;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    ...
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L1790vzo/8

*) *IE/Edge doesn't support CSS transforms on SVG elements at all.*
*) *Proper support in Chrome v64 and Opera v51*

Comment: I wonder what does `transform-origin` apply to? It seems to me that `transform-origin` applies to `rotate`, `scale` and `skew` but not to `translate`, is that correct? If I modify [this Pen](https://codepen.io/vineethtrv/pen/XKKEgM) then `transform-origin` doesn't seem to apply to `translate`

Answer (score 0):

If you know you want to rotate from a specific point, ie: the bottom left. You can apply the transform origin using the following keywords;

```
.hammer-icon {
    // x-offset y-offset 
    transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

Further reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: What if I want to rotate from a point other than the center and corners like the example above ?

Answer (score 0):

transform-origin:[x][y]

replace x and y with percentage values like 50% for mid, 0% for start and 100% for ending positions respectively. I’ve made a pen for helping you to understand this once and for all.

I wrote a complete article here: https://medium.com/@RajaRaghav/understanding-css-transform-origin-property-2ef5f8c50777 with illustrative examples