# Origin of CSS transform for svg:use

Tags: svg, css-transitions

Is there a way to set the origin of CSS animation (transform - rotation) relatively to x,y of the element `<use/>` with CSS?

There might be several `<use/>` in a given `<svg/>` at different places:
 absolute position of each element might not be hard coded in CSS.

```css
.spin {
  transition:4s linear;
  -webkit-transition:4s linear;
}
.spin:hover {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform:rotateZ(360eg);
  -webkit-transform:rotateZ(360deg);
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200"  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
      <defs>
        <path id="shape1" d="M0,0 V20 H20 Z" fill="red" stroke="red" stroke-width="0" />
      </defs>

      <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="80" fill="none" stroke="green"/>
      <use xlink:href="#shape1" x="40" y="40" class="spin" />
    </svg>
  </body>
```

Comment: Firefox supports [transform-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the transform origin to a specific point on the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397183/how-to-set-the-transform-origin-to-a-specific-point-on-the-element)

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks linked to transform is applied with the position of <path id="shape1" .../> "instead of" the position of <use href="#shape1" />
At least, that what I would expect.
In some cases, applying transform to <use/> like this is not the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animating the transform of a `<use>` is complicated by the fact that you are using the `x` and `y` attributes. [The spec says](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#struct-UseLayout) that:

> The x and y properties define an additional transformation (translate(x,y), ...

This extra transform component can mess with the transform you are animating, and produce unexpected effects.

The simple fix is to remove the `x` and `y` attributes, and use a parent `<g>` element to set the position of the path.

```
  <g transform="translate(40,40)">
    <use xlink:href="#shape1" class="spin" />
  </g>
```

**Updated example**

```css
.spin {
  transition:4s linear;
  -webkit-transition:4s linear;
}
.spin:hover {
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  transform:rotateZ(360eg);
  -webkit-transform:rotateZ(360deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200"  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
      <defs>
        <path id="shape1" d="M0,0 V20 H20 Z" fill="red" stroke="red" stroke-width="0" />
      </defs>

      <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="80" fill="none" stroke="green"/>
      <g transform="translate(40,40)">
        <use xlink:href="#shape1" class="spin" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
```