# Change pivot point of polygon

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a polygon that seems like it is having it pivot point in the corner. i want it in the middle so that i can rotate it around its center.

```html
<svg id="scroll-icon" width="25" height="45" viewBox="0 0 27 30" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g id="sc-romb" stroke="#1089C9">
      <polygon class="scroll-rotate" points="15 0 24 9 15.0009335 18 6 9" data-svg-origin="15 15" ></polygon>
      <polyline id="sc-arrow" points="28 16 14.9950568 29 2 16" data-svg-origin="15 22.5"></polyline>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I have tried using  `Transform-origin:center;` But if anyone has a better workaround that will work in most of the browsers, then i will be happy.

I also tried using the `transform: fill-box;` it DIDN'T work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the transform origin to a specific point on the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397183/how-to-set-the-transform-origin-to-a-specific-point-on-the-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you just want this?

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}

@keyframes rotatorooni {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.scroll-rotate {
  transform-origin: 15px 9px;
  animation: rotatorooni 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg id="scroll-icon" width="25" height="45" viewBox="0 0 27 30" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g id="sc-romb" stroke="#ff0000">
      <polygon class="scroll-rotate" points="15 0 24 9 15.0009335 18 6 9" data-svg-origin="15 15" ></polygon>
      <polyline id="sc-arrow" points="28 16 14.9950568 29 2 16" data-svg-origin="15 22.5"></polyline>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Except the problem is, visually it isn't very smooth since that lower center connection point at the bottom of that shape isn't actually in the center. So you'll either need to adjust your image accordingly to that `center center` is correct, or adjust the size into a size equally divisible so you can find the correct transform-origin with half pixel sizes of height and width to actually set it right on that point and make the animation appear smooth.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: no its only the polygon that is needed to be rolling, not the polyline.

Comment: @JessenJonas see the updated snippet, is that more of what you had in mind?