# Rotating SVG icon around its center

Tags: svg

I'm trying to rotate an SVG icon around its center, but this doesn't seem to behave as one would think. Here's the original SVG with the icon I'm trying to rotate.

```html
<svg width="692" height="502" style="background-color:white" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<symbol id="ToiletVertical" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 42 72">
    <path d="M40.762.542H.772v17.98h39.99V.542zM40.762 44.279s1.128 26.263-19.584 26.263C-.252 70.542.871 44.279.871 44.279l-.1-25.757h39.991v25.757z" fill="#fff" stroke="#000"/>
    <path d="M23.946 8.017h-6.357v3.03h6.357v-3.03z" fill="#fff" stroke="#000"/>
</symbol>

<path d="M481 447 499 447 499 479 481 479 "/> <use xlink:href="#ToiletVertical" x="481"  y="447" width="18.0" height="32.0"  fill="none" stroke="black" class="icon 5"/>
</svg>
```

Using `transform="rotate(180)"` will just throw the icon off completely. The same results will follow if I give rotate the corresponding (x, y) coordinates. Removing the x and y attributes of `<use>` and using `transform="translate(481, 448) rotate(180)` will rotate the icon, but it will still move off and doesn't go about its center. Could someone tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: Try CSS and `transform-box`/`transform-origin` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47399098/1869660

Answer (score 2):

In SVG you can rotate an element around a given point, for example this `transform="rotate(90,490, 463)"` rotates the element 90 degrees around the point x=490 and y=463.

You need to calculate the center of the use element and rotate it around this point. The use element has x="481" and width="18". The x of the center is 481 + 18/2 = 490. Do the same for the y and you'll get 463.

```html
<svg viewBox="440 410 100 100" width="300" style="background-color:white" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<symbol id="ToiletVertical" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 42 72">
    <path d="M40.762.542H.772v17.98h39.99V.542zM40.762 44.279s1.128 26.263-19.584 26.263C-.252 70.542.871 44.279.871 44.279l-.1-25.757h39.991v25.757z" fill="#fff" stroke="#000"/>
    <path d="M23.946 8.017h-6.357v3.03h6.357v-3.03z" fill="#fff" stroke="#000"/>
</symbol>

<path d="M481 447 499 447 499 479 481 479 "/>
  <use xlink:href="#ToiletVertical" x="481"  y="447" width="18.0" height="32.0"  fill="none" stroke="black" class="icon 5" transform="rotate(90,490, 463)"/>
</svg>
```