# SVG - debug or draw transform-origin - html, css

Tags: html, css, debugging, animation, svg

I have some strange pieces of svg for animate them, the problem is, them no are a 'img-box-style' so, when I put one in another, rotate, translate to another place, etc. know the `transform-origin` is important. I do it by hand using porcents and try-catch after I get them. But... there aren't one or two. So...

I need to 'see' the `transform-origin` point of a svg, I trying by using `::after`, adding anothers `div`s or `span`s, them inherit and works but not for svg. Finally i try using a `<circle>` but also, don't inherit, i don't know what to do.

Sometimes I need to put the circle in the middle of the two objects, in another time I need to put where the first fig start maybe  x: 10% y: 60%.
Lets said I put put `transform : 10% 60%;`  and see what I doing.

```css
body{margin:3rem;}
#svg-id{height: 75vh; background: rgb(216 86 228 / 25%);}

#svg-id g{
  /* transform-box: fill-box; */
  transform-origin: center; /* how i can 'see' the transform origin??? */
  /* animation: rotate 3s infinite linear; */
}

#svg-id g circle{
  fill: red;
  transform-origin: inherit; /* how inherit the transform origin??? */
}

@keyframes rotate{
  from{transform: rotate(0turn);}
  to  {transform: rotate(1turn);}
}
```

```html
<div>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg-id" viewBox="0 0 237.79 190.08">
    <g>
      <polygon points="12.21 129.77 40.5 150.42 136.21 115.91 44.66 90.08 12.21 129.77" />
      <polygon points="143.89 114.5 152.67 76.72 216.41 26.34 188.17 112.21 143.89 114.5" />
      <circle r=16 />
    </g>
  </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: You have changed the transform-origin of the svg g from left/top (default for svg) to center, and the elements rotate about the center which is the center of the mauvy bit. The <circle> is inheriting the transform-origin, but that isn't relevant for the animation you are setting which is on the whole group not the individual elements.  Are you wanting to put the red circle into the center? Are you wanting to do that by checking where the transform-origin has been set or do you know it's in the center?

Comment: I clarify more the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the transform origin to a specific point on the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397183/how-to-set-the-transform-origin-to-a-specific-point-on-the-element)

Comment: No. That question is about how set the transform origin... as you can see, here I put the transform-origin. The problem is than I can't 'see' it. Remember too, is a .svg

Comment: Sorry, could you explain a bit more for me? You have an svg and 'something' is setting its transform-origin but you don't know what it is but you'd like to put some sort of marker (eg. a small red circle) at the point that that transform-origin is? Have I got that right? Obviously if you know it's in the center of the element you can put a circle in the center, and that would solve the problem as far as the code you have given goes, but if 'someone/somewhere' sets the transform-origin to a different place you want the circle to go there.